# Is there a way to force the maximum in an amChart to be less than the maximum data value?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have data that is very skewed and because of one outlier the whole graph zooms out.I want to force the min-max values of the y axis ,so that most of the data in the graph is properly scaled.The outliers can go missing or be equal to the max/min values.They are not important.

Is there a way to do this without actually manipulating the data that is used as input for the chart ?
This is not the actual graph(I'll be using a line graph).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icemanreddy/y3z33sve/)

```
 var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.5;
    valueAxis.minimum = 00;
    valueAxis.maxumum=80;
    valueAxis.strictMinMax=true;
    valueAxis.dashLength = 3;
    chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You misspelled [`maximum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#maximum) as "maxumum", so your code doesn't work.

```
valueAxis.maximum = 80
```

Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3z33sve/1/).

Comment: *Facepalm*.
Thanks.